# should i use pthread or std::thread in project

Tags: c++, pthreads

When to use `pthread` and when to use `std::thread`? What's the difference between them?

I always use `std::thread` in my projects, but I've seen some open source projects use `pthread` in their projects, so how do you decide which to use?

Comment: std;:thread is standard and doesnt require an external library. So I'd go for the standard any day.